# Keyboard shortcut in Jshell to assign an expression to a local variable?

Tags: java, keyboard-shortcuts, jshell

For example, I want to type something like below in Jshell

```
new Random().nextInt()
```

and then use a keyboard shortcut to generate a local variable with the correct return type.

```
int x = new Random().nextInt()
```

Is there any in-built or user-defined shortcut to achieve the above? if not any workaround?

Comment: not sure if that helps, but if I recall correctly, every time you type the first line and press enter, a variable(`$1`) that you can reference in that session is generated

Comment: Yes, you are right. However, here, I am rather interested to see the type of variable especially if it is a complex type. eclipse provides similar functionality with the keyboard shortcut "ctrl+2, L"